# Generating uniformly distributed random variables with given mean and deviation

Tags: random

I don't understand maths very well so sorry for my newbie question.

Imagine I have a bank and clients of this bank. Clients arrive following a uniform distribution with $3.5$ mean and $1.3$ standard deviation.

How can I calculate a random number with this data?

I know that $f(x) = \frac{1}{(b-a)}$ on the interval $[a,b]$. So

$$P(c\leq X \leq d) = \frac{(d-c)}{(b-a)}$$

In my example, $a$ and $b$ will be generated using a random generator but I don't understand how I can generate a random number following a uniform distribution with my mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First will come the pretty complete theory. Then we look at your particular situation.

**Theory:** We need an expression for the variance of $X$. The variance  is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. For $E(X^2)$, we need to calculate
$$\int_a^b \frac{x^2}{b-a}\,dx,$$
which is $\frac{b^3-a^3}{3(b-a)}$. This simplifies to $\frac{b^2+ab+a^2}{3}$.

I imagine that you know that  $E(X)=\frac{b+a}{2}$. One can do this by integration, but it is clear by symmetry that the mean is halfway between $a$ and $b$.

So we know that the variance is $\frac{b^2+ab+a^2}{3}-\frac{(b+a)^2}{4}$. Bring to a common denominator, simplify. We get that 
$$\text{Var}(X)=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12} \tag{$\ast$}.$$
More simply, you can search under uniform distribution, say on Wikipedia. They will have the expression $(\ast)$ for the variance of $X$.

**Your problem:**  We know that  $\frac{b+a}{2}=3.5$. We also know that the standard deviation of $X$ is $1.3$, so the variance is $(1.3)^2=1.69$.

So, by $(\ast)$,  $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}=1.69$, and therefore $b-a=\sqrt{(12)(1.69)}\approx 4.5033$. We also know that $b+a=(2)(3.5)=7$. Now that we know $b-a$ and $b+a$, it is easy to find $a$ and $b$.

For your simulation, presumably you are starting from a random number generator that generates numbers that are more or less uniformly distributed on $[0,1)$. If $U$ represents the output of such a generator, we simulate $X$ by using $a+(b-a)U$. And we now know $a$ and $b$.

**Added** If you want a general formula instead of a procedure, let $\mu=\frac{a+b}{2}$ be the mean, and $\sigma=\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{12}}=\frac{b-a}{2\sqrt{3}}$ be the standard deviation. Then $\frac{b-a}{2}=\sqrt{3}\,\sigma$. 
We get $a=\frac{b+a}{2}-\frac{b-a}{2}=\mu-\sqrt{3}\,\sigma$. It follows that we can take
$$X=\mu-\sqrt{3}\,\sigma + (2\sqrt{3}\,\sigma) U=\mu+(\sqrt{3}\,\sigma)(2U-1).$$

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So given my mean of $3.5$ and sdt of $1,3$ and $U$ of $0,2$, $a$ would be $1,2483$, $b$ would be $5,7516$ and $X=2,14896$?

Comment: @Favolas: I checked your calculation above. Agree.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question. Could this be done $X = mean - 0.5 + sdt * sqrt(12) * U$ ?

Comment: I will add a formula of this type (but different) to the post.

Comment: Thanks. Don't quite understand the $Subtract$ part but thanks for the last formula. Comparing yours with mine give quite different results. Many many thanks

Comment: @Favolas: Since that confused you, I deleted that one-word sentence. The point is that by algebra, $a=\frac{b+a}{2}-\frac{b-a}{2}$ (just simplify the right-hand side). I wanted $a+(b-a)U$. Since we know $(b+a)/2=\mu$ and $(b-a)/2=\sqrt{3}\sigma$, the rest is just substitution.

Comment: Thanks so mutch for your time, patience and very useful explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a uniformly distributed continuous random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Then 
$$
    X = \mu + 2 \sqrt{3} \sigma \left( U - \frac{1}{2} \right)
$$
where $U$ is a random variables [uniformly distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) on a unit interval. 
Indeed:
$$
  \mathbb{E}(X) = \mu + \sqrt{3} \sigma \mathbb{E}(2U-1) = \mu
$$
$$
  \mathbb{Var}(X) = (2 \sqrt{3} \sigma)^2 \mathbb{Var}(U-1/2) = 12 \sigma^2 \mathbb{Var}(U) = \sigma^2
$$
and, assuming both $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the domain of $X$,
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \mathbb{P}( x_1 < X \leqslant x_2) &=& 
   \mathbb{P}\left( x_1 < \mu + 2 \sqrt{3} \sigma \left( U - \frac{1}{2} \right) \leqslant x_2\right) \\
  &=& \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{x_1 - \mu}{2 \sqrt{3} \sigma} < U \leqslant \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x_2 - \mu}{2 \sqrt{3} \sigma}  \right) \\
   &=& x_2-x_1
\end{eqnarray}
$$